# Где посмотреть точный список собираемой информации о пользователе в Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, android, база-данных, ios, google-analytics

Для мобильного приложения нужно определить точный список данных, которые собираются о пользователе через GA. Где можно найти этот список?